# Is there a way to stop RGui from crashing when an RCPP program fails to work correctly?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm using Rcpp to run C++ code using RGui (version 3.4.1) as a user interface. Quite often I make changes to the C++ code which compile correctly but cause errors (e.g. searching beyond the end of an array) when I run the relevant program in RGui, causing RGui to crash. This is aggravating because I have to re-open RGui, re-open my R script (sometimes with unsaved changes lost), set the working directory again, etc. before I can re-compile the C++ code and run the program in such a way as to find the problem or test amendments. Sometimes it promptly crashes again because I haven't fixed or bypassed the problem.

Is there some way to change the way Rcpp runs such that RGui returns an error message instead of crashing in these sorts of situations?

Answer (score 5):

Briefly:

1. It is spelled Rcpp. Capital R, lowercase cpp.
2. Yes, don't have bugs :)
3. In general, 2. is the only viable answer.  If you need a managed language, use R.
4. If the code takes your environment down, *test outside the environment*. Seriously.  That is for example why I (co-)wrote [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) and test "raw code" on the command-line: it can only take the command-line app down.
5. We *do* have a feature in eg RcppArmadillo to test for "out of bounds" vector access: use `x.at(i,j)` which will warn. See http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access

Comment: I'm using C++ code which was originally created to be run on its own (and was debugged and fixed up at that point) and tweaking it to be able to use RGui as a user interface. So it's the

Comment: (Sorry, hit Return and posted accidentally too early)

Fixed the Rcpp capitalization error.

I'm using C++ code which I originally created, tested and ran in Visual Studio (where a similar error only closes the run window), and just tweaking it to use RGui as a user interface. So it's mainly the Rcpp bits that I'm testing, along with the outputs (to files and to the console window).

Comment: Have you tried the R development tools for Visual Studio (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/rtvs/)? I only know that they exist, but with the two IDEs for R that I have experience with (RStudio and Emacs + ESS), you don't lose anything if you write R commands into file which are then send to the R interpreter.

Comment: I would say that _in the long run_ you are better off not chaining yourself to any one IDE.  What you want here is a _traceback_ so compile with `-g` and launch `R -d gdb` and see if you can get useful information from the crash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know of a way to prevent this apart from more careful programming, and saving before execution. But having done this a few times I have discovered a way to get back at unsaved changes, (at least in windows).

When you get the pop-up that tells you to restart R, you don't do it. You open up task manager and right-click on the process and select 'Create Dump File'. Find this file in explorer and open it with some text editor.

They are very big, and full of all sorts of stuff, but if you use find function to search for some string you know to be in your script, then you can find all the unsaved work. You can then copy and paste this into another file to save.

If you use R-studio instead of R-GUI, it usually manages to look after your unsaved work better.